# Skip First inserted record of Id list in Postgress sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

In postgressql I have a data with multiple articleId list on table.
For example I have 3 records with 2 records of same articleId and 1 record of different articleId.
Whereever I query

```
select * from table where articleId in (1,2,3) order by date
```

It will return all 3 records. Now I am looking for solution to skip first inserted record of each articleId.

I tried of using **OFFSET** but it skip first row not with each articleId first inserted record.

```
Sample data:

| id | name  | articleId |      date           |
|:---|:-----:| ---------:| -------------------:|
| 1  | abc   | 1200      | 2021-06-01 06:09:35 |
| 2  | bcd   | 1400      | 2021-05-01 06:08:35 |
| 3  | xyz   | 1200      | 2021-06-01 09:09:35 |
| 4  | qwe   | 1600      | 2021-06-01 07:09:32 |



Expected query Output:

| id | name  | articleId |      date           |
|:---|:-----:| ---------:| -------------------:|
| 2  | bcd   | 1400      | 2021-05-01 06:08:35 |
```

Comment: Do you want to skip first row even it's a single row in the table for  articleId?

Comment: If there is a single row of particular articleId it should skip and return empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from (
  select * , row_number() over (partition by articleId order by date) rn
  from table
) t
where t.rn > 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but above query is not as per my solution. I looking for to skip first inserted record of particular articleId list and to fetch next inserted record of particular articleId.

Comment: that's what this query does . you need to ptovide more information , sample data and desired output

Comment: yours query working as expected but it taking more time if there are more data. Is there any solution?

Comment: You need an index on (articleid, date)

Answer (score 0):

> Now I am looking for solution to skip first inserted record of each articleId.

One simple method is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.articleId in (1, 2) and
      t.date > (select min(t2.date) from t t2 where t2.articleid = t.articleid);
```

For performance, you want an index on `(articleid, date)`.

Comment: thanks for you solution, it working as expected but it taking more time to execute query with more data. Is there any solution for it.

Comment: @Priya . . . Try with the suggested index.